# Using "if" and "else" with smarty template system?

Tags: php, smarty

Here's the variable I'm working with in Smarty:

```
{$productinfo.pid}
```

That variable will always be a number value.  If they number is 8-76 then I want it to show a message that says "This Works".  If it's 1-7 or above 76, I want it to show "Now Working".

Is anyone familiar with how to do this with smarty?

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl

Comment: This is either an extremely basic programming question (how to compare numbers) or something which you could have found in 10 seconds using any search engine (how to perform an "if" in Smarty).

Answer (score 1):

Smarty's [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl) is good for this type of problem.

```
{if $productinfo.pid < 8 or $productinfo.pid > 76 }
   NOT WORKING
{else}
   WORKING
{/if}
```